# C shift right not working correctly on int types in my program

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have the following function in C:

```
int lrot32(int a, int n)
{
    printf("%X SHR %d = %X\n",a, 32-n, (a >> (32-n)));
    return ((a << n) | (a >> (32-n)));
}
```

When I pass as arguments lrot32(0x8F5AEB9C, 0xB) I get the following:

```
8F5AEB9C shr 21 = FFFFFC7A
```

However, the result should be 47A. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Note that the title of your question implies that a lot of programs are not working.

Comment: Have you *tried* to shove `0x8F5AEB9C` into an `int` on your platform?

Comment: When working with bits and bitwise operations, *always* use unsigned types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a signed integer type. [C11 6.5.7p4-5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7) says the following:

> 4 The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and *E1 x 2<sup>E2</sup>* is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined.**
>
> 5 The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. [...] if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup> . **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.**

Thus in the case of `<<`, if the shifted value is negative, or the positive value after shift is not representable in the result type (here: `int`), the behaviour is undefined; in the case of `>>`, if the value is negative the result is *implementation defined*.

Thus in either case, you'd get results that at least depend on the implementation, and in the case of left-shift, worse, possibly on the optimization level and such. A strictly conforming program cannot rely on any particular behaviour.

---

If however you want to target a particular compiler, then check its manuals on what the behaviour - if any is specified - would be. For example [GCC says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> The results of some bitwise operations on signed integers (C90 6.3,
>   C99 and C11 6.5).
>
> Bitwise operators act on the representation of the value including
>   both the sign and value bits, where the sign bit is considered
>   immediately above the highest-value value bit. **Signed ‘>>’ acts on
>   negative numbers by sign extension.** [*]
>
> As an extension to the C language, **GCC does not use the latitude given
>   in C99 and C11 only to treat certain aspects of signed ‘<<’ as
>   undefined.** However, -fsanitize=shift (and -fsanitize=undefined) will
>   diagnose such cases. They are also diagnosed where constant
>   expressions are required.

[*] sign extension here means that the sign bit - which is `1` for negative integers, is repeated by the shift amountwhen right-shift is executed - this is why you see those `F`s in the result.

Furthermore GCC always requires 2's complement representation, so if you would *always* use GCC, no matter which architecture you're targeting, this is the behaviour you'd see. Also, in the future someone might use another compiler for your code, thus causing other behaviour there.

---

Perhaps you'd want to use unsigned integers - `unsigned int` or rather, if a certain width is expected, then for example `uint32_t`, as the shifts are always well-defined for it, and would seem to match your expectations.

---

Another thing to note is that not all shift amounts are allowed. [C11 6.5.7 p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3):

> [...]If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Thus if you ever shift an unsigned integer having width of 32 bits by 32 - left or right, the behaviour is **undefined**. This should be kept in mind. Even if the compiler wouldn't do anything wacky, some processor architectures do act as if shift by 32 would then shift all bits away - others behave as if the shift amount was 0.

Comment: It might be worth noting that on most of today's implementations the *sign bit* is shifted in on `>>` - This is what the OP sees.

Comment: `uint32_t` would be a better type, since the intent seems to be 32-bit operations