# segmentation fault when trying to pass two array pointers to a function that swaps them randomly

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to swap two pointers in the same array 52 times using a function within a for-loop. I am getting a segmentation fault and i'm not sure where the issue is.

Here's my code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "shuffle.h"

extern void shuffle(int** tempPtr1 , int** tempPtr2);
extern void deal(int numPlayers, int numHands, int** tempPtr2);

int main(void) {
    int numPlayers;
    int numHands;
    int randomNum;

    printf("Enter number of players: ");
    scanf("%d", &numPlayers);

    printf("Enter number of hands per player: ");
    scanf("%d", &numHands);

    int card[52] = {0};
    char faces[] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','X', 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
    char suit[] = {'S', 'D', 'H', 'C'};

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {

        card[i] = suit[i/13];
        card[i] = card[i] << CHAR_BIT;
        card[i] = card[i] | faces[i%13];
    }
    int *firstIndxPtr;
    firstIndxPtr = &card[0];
    int *randIndxPtr1;

    for(int i = 0; i<52;i++){
        randomNum = rand() % 52 + 1;
        randIndxPtr1 = &card[randomNum];
        shuffle(&firstIndxPtr, &randIndxPtr1);
    }
    deal(numPlayers, numHands, &firstIndxPtr);
}
```

and then my function shuffle:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void shuffle(int** tempPtr1 , int** tempPtr2);

void shuffle(int** tempPtr1 , int** tempPtr2)
{       
    int* tempPtr = *tempPtr2;
    *tempPtr2 = *tempPtr1;
    *tempPtr1 = tempPtr;
}
```

the function should swap the pointer address of the 0 index in the card array with the pointer address of a random index in the card array. This would then be done 52 times in the for loop, creating a fully shuffled array. Instead I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Are you sure that the segmetation fault happens in shuffle and not in another point (deal() for example) ?

Comment: @P.Antoniadis I have completely removed deal() from main and still get the fault.

Comment: don't think it's the problem, but use caution when shifting signed types,, usually best to stick to unsigned types for bitwise operations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859950/3476780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spot two overruns in the posted code which could lead to a segfault:

First, `rand() % 52 + 1` ranges from 1 to 52, inclusive, which means roughly 2% of the time `card[randomNum]` will be past the end of `card`.

Second, `shuffle` swaps which addresses two pointers point to, not the contents of the memory at those two addresses. So `shuffle(&firstIndxPtr, &randIndxPtr1)` just changes where in the (unmodified) `card` array `firstIndxPtr` and `randIndxPtr1` point. Because `randIndxPtr1` is always at least the second element of `card`, `firstIndxPtr` is guaranteed to be past the start of `card` at the end of this (as above, it may even end up past the end of `card`). Presumably `deal` expects to be able to access 52 elements of `card` when at most 51 elements (possibly as few as -1) are actually available past `firstIndexPtr`.

Comment: would the solution to the second problem be to initialize the firstIndxPtr to card[0] at the start of every loop and after the loop is done? Or would I need to change the function to pass the pointers instead of the pointer addresses?

Comment: The latter: the function should take `int*` instead of `int**` and should be called on the pointers directly instead of on their addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
 randomNum = rand() % 52 + 1;
```

Because rand()%52 is a number between 0 and 51. So, after adding 1 you have a number between 1 and 52. In case, rand()%52 is 51 randomNum is 52 and here:

```
randIndxPtr1 = &card[randomNum];
```

you access index 52 in an array with size  52. So, don't add 1 to randomNum.